# How do I add a FooterView here?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a custom adapter which formats for me, alphabet headers and then corresponding names underthem, but I want to put a unique footer at the bottom that will display the number of contacts, for example "Total number of contacts in list: 21"

```
 class LetterAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    LetterAdapter() {
        super(ContactProjectActivity.this, R.layout.row, R.id.label, sortedNames);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        }

        TextView label = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.label);   
        label.setText(sortedNames.get(position));

        if (sortedNames.get(position).length() == 1) {
            //label.setText("The size is " + searchNames.size());
            label.setTextSize(15);
            row.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        }
        else {
            label.setTextSize(20);
            label.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            row.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
        return(row);

    }
}
```

I am extending ListActivity so I don't have a ListView variable in my code. Any code snippets or suggestions would be helpful.

I want to customize the footer also, with its own background color (similar to how I did the letter headers in the code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the `ListView` from you `ListActivity` with the method `getListView()` and then try to set your footer view before you set the adapter.

Comment: +1 and @JayLefler: Better is to do some search before posting a question, For [example](http://tinyurl.com/6hdkel4)

Comment: I did search before posting, but I didn't find any example where the text was set. I understand the logic of creating a seperate xml file for the footer, but how do I then set the text of the TextView for the footer?

Comment: @JayLefler what are you trying to put as a footer? If you have a xml layout for the footer view you can inflate the xml and then search for the TextView(by it's id) from that layout(this is what i understood you are trying to do) and make the proper initializations.

Comment: I have a list of names, and I want to put the total number in the list at the footer.

Comment: public class ListWithFooter extends ListActivity {

 private String[] names = { "Name", "Name", "Name", "Name", "Name"};
 private TextView displayNumbers;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  displayNumbers = new TextView(this);
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);
  displayNumbers.setText("The number of names in this list is: "
    + adapter.getCount());
  getListView().addFooterView(displayNumbers);
  getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
 }

}